# Sharing Interactive IPython/Jupyter Notebooks for Non-Technical Users

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, jupyterhub

Is there an optimal way to share/serve a readonly-ish Jupyter notebooks with the input code cells hidden, but connected to a live kernel so users can interact with widgets?

I understand there are ways to embed data for widgets, but often the widgets require rerunning a query against a larger data sets.

I've recently started learning to use widgets and they'd be really useful to share interactive data with our non-technical staff, but I haven't figured out a good way to do so yet.

Having this capability would also reduce the desire for expensive tools like Tableau.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [kyso.io](https://kyso.io) (disclaimer: I founded kyso) you can share notebooks online easily:

- It will you can show/hide code so non-technical people can read it
- Interactive visualisations work perfectly, like bokeh and plotly.

Heres some examples:

- https://kyso.io/laura/bokeh-example
- https://kyso.io/laura/gauss-fitting

you can share a notebook using these commands

```
kyso create "some study title"
kyso push "a version message"
```

Currently the notebooks are static renderings, but soon we are going to host 
runnable Jupyter dashboards.

Comment: links are broken unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Take a look Apache Zeppelin https://zeppelin.apache.org. Which is closest opensource software that you can share a notebook with code hidden and let other users run it. Apache Zeppelin has [Dynamic form](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/manual/dynamicform.html), which is not exactly widgets but used for the same purpose. Zeppelin supports notebook level access control so you can achieve what you want.(disclaimer: I'm creator of Apache Zeppelin)

You can also take a look notebook sharing service https://www.zepl.com. Which enables

- Access control on the notebook
- Notebook updates auto synced from Github / S3
- Report looknfeel (Hide code for non-technical people)
- Comments on the cells
- Team and Workspace to organize sharing
- Both Jupyter notebook and Zeppelin notebook format support

This can be an possible alternative on sharing your notebook with non-technical users. (disclaimer: I'm co-founder of ZEPL)